# Padding issue on HTML email

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I have an issue with excess padding appearing around either the table or image on mobile with a HTML email signature and I'm unable to find the solution.

I must of tried every single solution I have researched including:

- Adding display:block to the image
- Adding a line-height: 1px to the td
- Adding font-size: 0; to the td
- Making sure every section had padding: 0; and margin: 0;
- Adding cellpadding="0" and cellspacing="0" to all tables, tr and td elements
- Adding width and height to the table and td (which didn't have any effect)
- Adding float: left and align="left"
- Adding table-layout:fixed;
- Adding border: 0; border-spacing: 0; and border-collapse; on elements

The issue seems to appear on Samsung and iPhone devices that I have tested.

Any new suggestions would be appreciated.

The image that specifically has extra spacing is here:

```
<table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; table-layout:fixed; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; padding:0; margin: 0; float:left; line-height: 1px; font-size: 0;" width="180"> 
    <tr style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <td valign="bottom" style="padding:0 25px 0 0; margin:0; font-size: 0 !important;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><img src="logo.png" width="" alt="" style="display: block !important;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How here is the entire code as I have two tables side by side which may be the cause of the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a {
    color: #00001b;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
table {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; max-width: 367px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>    
    <td>            
        <table style="border-bottom: 3px solid #000; padding-bottom: 8px;" width="367" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; padding:0; margin: 0;" border="0" height="10">
                    <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; table-layout:fixed; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; padding:0; margin: 0; float:left; line-height: 1px; font-size: 0;" width="180"> 
                        <tr style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                            <td valign="bottom" style="padding:0 25px 0 0; margin:0; font-size: 0 !important;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><img src="logo.png" width="" alt="" style="display: block !important; padding: 0; margin: 0;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 7px 0; line-height:1px; font-size:0; float:left;">
                        <tr>
                            <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="165" style="text-align: left;">
                                <strong style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Garamond;">First Name Last Name</strong><br />
                                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 100%;"><em>Job Title / GIA GG, BA</em></span><br />          
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <p style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 160%; margin: 10px 0;">
    <strong>T:</strong> <a href="tel:0000000">00000000</a> | 
    <strong>W:</strong> <a href="http://www.website.com.au">www.website.com.au</a><br /> Street Address | City | State Postcode</p>
    <p style="margin:6px 0;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="28" height="28"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="28" height="28"></a></p>
    </td>   
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Mobile View]

[image: Desktop View]

Comment: Hi DanyAlejandro, The code is for an email template, hence the use of tables and inline css.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; max-width: 367px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>    
        <td>            
            <table style="border-bottom: 3px solid #000; padding-bottom: 8px;" width="345" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="180"> 
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="bottom" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><img src="logo.png" width="180" height="100" alt="" style="display: block"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="165">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: left;padding:0 0 0 25px;">
                                    <strong style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Garamond;">First Name Last Name</strong><br />
                                    <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 100%;"><em>Job Title / GIA GG, BA</em></span><br />          
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                    
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        <p style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 160%; margin: 10px 0;">
        <strong>T:</strong> <a href="tel:0000000">00000000</a> | 
        <strong>W:</strong> <a href="http://www.website.com.au">www.website.com.au</a><br /> Street Address | City | State Postcode</p>
        <p style="margin:6px 0;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="28" height="28"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="28" height="28"></a></p>
        </td>   
    </tr>
</table>
```

You may want to add a `</td><td>` between your two tables. I've also moved the 25px padding to the left of the copy, rather than the image. (I've assumed the img dimensions here). This looked ok on my EoA previews, if it doesn't help could you post a screenshot of your issue?

Comment: If it was for an email template i would have said go with ghost columns but this will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the issue with adding a td is that the two tables no longer collapse underneath each other on mobile. I have attached two screenshots. The top view is the desktop view which is fine. The bottom is the mobile view which as you can see has too much padding around the image. If you have any more suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Code it like an email! Try the hybrid method! This method allows you to cater for outlook email clients and the use of divs means you dont have to worry about the extra gaps.

```html
<table style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; max-width: 367px;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>    
    <td>            
        <table style="border-bottom: 3px solid #000; padding-bottom: 8px;" width="367" cellspacing="0">
            <tr style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                               
                   <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: top; font-size: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 367px;">   
                    
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="367" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="180">
<![endif]-->
<div style="width: 180px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
<table align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; table-layout:fixed; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; padding:0; margin: 0; float:left; line-height: 1px; font-size: 0;" width="100%"> 
                        <tr style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                            <td valign="bottom" style="padding:0 25px 0 0; margin:0; font-size: 0 !important;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><img src="logo.png" width="" alt="" style="display: block !important; padding: 0; margin: 0;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</div>
          
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="180">
<![endif]-->

<div style="width: 180px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 7px 0; line-height:1px; font-size:0; float:left;" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="165" style="text-align: left;">
                                <strong style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Garamond;">First Name Last Name</strong><br />
                                <span style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 100%;"><em>Job Title / GIA GG, BA</em></span><br />          
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
</div>

 <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
                    
                    
                    
                    
                                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <p style="font-size: 11px; line-height: 160%; margin: 10px 0;">
    <strong>T:</strong> <a href="tel:0000000">00000000</a> | 
    <strong>W:</strong> <a href="http://www.website.com.au">www.website.com.au</a><br /> Street Address | City | State Postcode</p>
    <p style="margin:6px 0;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="facebook.png" alt="Facebook" width="28" height="28"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com"><img src="instagram.png" alt="Instagram" width="28" height="28"></a></p>
    </td>   
</tr>

</table>
```

Let me know if this method works for you.

Comment: Hi Syfer, I still seem to have the same padding issue and the tables no longer collapse on mobile. Any other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using media queries to stack? If you are using media query, can you update your post with the most current code so i can see whats happening?

Comment: No, I'm not using media queries as they aren't supported by gmail. I have updated my question to add in css located in the <head> but it's mostly cosmetic.

Comment: So this is going directly into Gmail as a signature or part of am email? Btw Gmail supports media queries now.

Comment: *mind blown* I didn't realise Gmail had started supporting media queries. It's going into Outlook as an email signature but when I send an email to Gmail it doesn't display as required.

Comment: So it's an outlook signature specifically or part of an email template?

Comment: Just an outlook email signature.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be in this category. Outlook signatures are simple signatures. Stacking will be difficult as most of the codes don't usually work on them. I would suggest designing something around 300px and working around that size so all screens are catered for.